# Centering UI elements with flex, in React

Tags: css, react.js, pokemon, next.js

I'm using React and Tailwind to generate cards like the example below. I was hoping to get feedback on the CSS rules I used, the order of the Tailwind classnames, and the HTML structure. I'm using `flex` in several places because I'm used to it, but isn't there a better alternative "best practices"-wise?

Example card, Mega Sceptile:

[image: Example card for Mega Sceptile]

In `Icon`, the pokémon type icons are wrapped in a div with the matching colored background. I used flex to make sure the icon is fully centered.
Note that `Image` is an element provided by Next.js and requires passing `weight` and `height`, so I approximated `height: 60%` with `30 * 0.6`.

In `Card` I `justify-around` the text and icon divs to keep them off the sides, while using flex `basis-20` to make sure the icons are closer to the edge than the text, and that the text takes most of the space.

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react';

import { Pokemon } from '@/types/pokemon.ts';

function Icon({ type }: { type: string }) {
  return (
    // flex used to center the type icon inside the colored div
    <div className={`${type} h-[30px] w-[30px] flex rounded-full transition-all hover:saturate-200 hover:scale-110`}>
      <Image
        src={`type-icons/${type}.svg`}
        alt={type}
        title={type}
        width={30 * 0.6}
        height={30 * 0.6}
        className='m-[20%]'
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Card({ pokemon }: { pokemon: Pokemon }) {
  const { id, name, sprite, type1, type2 } = pokemon;

  // names and extensions (like "mega") are provided in lower case
  // and separated by hyphens
  const [n, ...extensions] = name.split('-');

  return (
    <div className='h-[23vh] p-1 grid bg-white border-gray-200 border-[1px] hover:bg-gray-200 hover:cursor-pointer'>
      <div className='flex justify-around '>
        <div className='basis-20'>
          <p className='text-gray-600'>{id}</p>
          {/* Capitalize first letter of name */}
          <p className='text-gray-500'>{n?.replace(/\b\w/, c => c.toUpperCase())}</p>
          <p className='text-gray-300 text-xs'>{extensions.join(' ')}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-between'>
          <Icon type={type1} />
          {type2 && <Icon type={type2} />}
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={sprite} alt={name} className='m-auto' />
    </div>
  );
}
```